# Splitting an html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split

```
<div id="id1">
    "Hi HElP ME
    <br>
    <p>ok<p>
    <div>
         <img class = "some class src="">
    </div>
    <b>ok1<b>
    <div>
         <img class = "some class src="">
    </div>
    <p>end<p>
</div>

I want to split this html content such tha output will be:

$("#id1").find('img').each(function(){
    var result = somefunction(this)
    alert(result)
    //After first loop- "Hi HElP ME<br><p>ok<p>
    // Second time =<b>ok1<b>
    // third time  = <p>end<p>
})
```

Could anyone give me demo for this.As number of images are not shown so please give me a general solution

Comment: The `id` of your `<div>` isn't `id1`.

Comment: #id1 should just be #1, the # is what tells jQuery it is looking for an id.

Comment: Don't use numbers as id's.

Comment: It may be valid but it's not good practice - it has no semantic value at all.

Comment: Your HTML is not correctly formatted to return your desired results.  You have `img`s in some of the `div`s, and the text is not always in the same location (text is only sometimes in the `p`).  You should check out `$.text()` for returning the inner text of the `div` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#id1').find('img').each(function(index){


var split_text = $(this).html().split(/<img[^>]*>/)[index];
alert(split_text)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your id selector is referenced incorrectly.  It should be $("#1") instead of $("#id1").

Easy mistake to make, but hard to find.