# Selecting an image inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div>
    <div id ="container">
       <div>
           <img src="some src>
       </div>
       <p>get this text</p>
       <h>hello</h>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want the total number of images inside a main div and want to extract html tags other than image tag.
OUTPUT:
No. of images =1 
strings= `<p>get this text</p><h>hello</h>`

please give me a demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#container img").length` - For `img` tag count

To extract strings for each,

```
$("#container").find("p, h").not("div").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).get(0)); //Object
});
```

Note: You are using some weird <s>`<h>`</s> element which is an invalid HTML tag, I think its `<h1>` or some other header element.

Comment: i don't know which tag are in html page so can i write something like this find(everything but not img)

Comment: @SomPathak Yes, for everything, use `*`

Comment: would you look at this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963843/splitting-an-html-tags) if we want to break html string whenever a img tags come

Comment: @SomPathak Are we done with this one? did it solved your issue?

Comment: ya but i want something like this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963843/splitting-an-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#container').find('img').length
```

Comment: im my html page there are may divs but i want image which is inside container div only

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/nosin/5/edit

JS:

```
var a = $('#container').find('img').length;

console.log('No. of images =' + a);

var b = $('#container').find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p');
var c = '';

for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  c += b[i].outerHTML;
}

console.log('strings=' + c);
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div id ="container">
     <div>
       <img src="some src"/>
     </div>
     <p>get this text</p>
     <h1>hello</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

OUTPUT:

```
"No. of images =1"
"strings=<p>get this text</p><h1>hello</h1>"
```

Comment: would you look at this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963843/splitting-an-html-tags) if we want to break html string whenever a img tags come

Comment: He wants literal strings, not the count

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one it will help you.

```
$(document).on("click", "#container", function(){
    var img = $(this).find("img"), // select images inside container
        len = img.length; // check if they exist
    if( len > 0 ){
        // images found, get id
        var attrID = img.first().attr("src"); // get src attr of first image
    } else {
        // images not found
    }
});
//For multiple images
var arr = []; // create array
if( len > 0 ){
    // images found, get src
    img.each(function(){ // run this for each image
        arr.push( $(this).attr("src") ); // push each image's src to the array
    });
} else {
    // images not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try this :

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var no_of_img = jQuery('#container img').length;
    $("#container").find("*").each(function() {
      var obj = $(this).get(0); //Object
      if($(obj).find("img").length > 0 || $(obj).is("img")){

      }else{
        console.log($(obj).get(0));
      }
    });
   });
  </script>
```